# How to create command in usercontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, model-view-controller, icommand

I'm developing my first application in WPF with the pattern MVC and I have a question.

I have created a usercontrol from type `Grid` to made a custom title bar. This grid contains a X button and I want to associate this button to a command.

My grid in XAML:

```
<Grid x:Class="Views.TitleBarView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyleGrid}"
      x:Name="barView">

    <Label x:Name="labelAppName" Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyleLabel}" Content="Title"/>
    <Button x:Name="bttnClose" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleCloseWindow}" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonMinimize" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleMinimizeWindow}"  Command="{Binding MinimizeCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

The C# view:

```
public partial class TitleBarView : Grid
{
    public TitleBarView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TitleBarViewModel tvm = new TitleBarViewModel();
        tvm.RequestClose += (s, e) => this.Close();
        tvm.RequestMinimize+= (s, e) => this.Minimize();
        DataContext = tvm;
    }

    private void Close()
    {
            Window.GetWindow(this).Close();
    }

    private void Minimize()
    {
            Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized;
    }
}
```

The C# viewModel:

```
public class TitleBarViewModel : ViewModelBase, IRequestMinimizeViewModel, IRequestCloseViewModel
{
    private RelayCommand minimizeCommand;
    protected RelayCommand closeCommand;
    public event EventHandler RequestMinimize;
    public event EventHandler RequestClose;

    #region MinimizeCommand
    public ICommand MinimizeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (minimizeCommand == null)
            {
                minimizeCommand = new RelayCommand(Minimize);
            }
            return minimizeCommand;
        }
    }


    private void Minimize()
    {
        RequestMinimize(this, null);
    }
    #endregion

    #region CloseCommand
    public ICommand CloseCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (closeCommand == null)
            {
                closeCommand = new RelayCommand(Close);
            }
            return closeCommand;
        }
    }

    protected void Close()
    {
        RequestClose(this, null);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I saw that it's not recommended to set a DataContext on a userControl. And when I do this, I can't change the close command. For example I want that when the main windows calls command close it calls `Application.Current.Shutdown();` instead of `Application.Current.Shutdown();`

I know that I have something wrong but I'm too confuse to solve it. Can you explain me how to create command for userControl ? (Or just tell me what I'm doing wrong)

Thank you

Comment: How can you develop a WPF application using an **MVC pattern?**

Comment: You can create UI-only commands (RoutedCommand), but from my experience you shouldn't. I'd say you should use two different commands in two different viewmodels (for mainwindow and TitleBarView) UPD: don't know about MVC practices

Comment: If you have a view-model you certainly are not using MVC, but MVVM...

Comment: Application.Current.Shutdown(); instead of Application.Current.Shutdown(); wat

Comment: You are right, I mean MVVM I confound both.
And I have done a bad paste, I want to call `Window.GetWindow(this).Close();` on my windows and `Application.Current.Shutdown();` on the main for command close